# java lanterna can not read input from terminal

Tags: java, lanterna

I have problems using the readInput() method from the lanterna package. My codefraction

```
    Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createSwingTerminal();
    terminal.enterPrivateMode();
    Key key = terminal.readInput();
    if(key.getKind()==Key.Kind.Escape){
    terminal.moveCursor(6, 6);
    terminal.putCharacter('X');
```

doesn't allow me to do any input in the terminal and therefore creates a nullpointerexception when checking for key.getKind. Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readInput` method is non-blocking. It means that it will not hang until a input is found (as i.e. `Scanner` does). So you will need your own "blocking method" which waits for an input:

```
Key key = terminal.readInput();
while(key == null) {
    Thread.sleep(5); //whatever low value
    key = terminal.readInput();
}
// here key will not be null, so no NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an updated answer here. As of lanterna 3.1.1, the readInput() method is now blocking. This means that it will hang until a user inputs.

You should use pollInput() instead, as this is the new non-blocking method.